# Python MySQLdb connection to online database

Tags: python, mysql

While I have no problems to connect to my localhost database that way:

```
import MySQLdb

localdb = MySQLdb.connect( host="127.0.0.1",    
                           user="root",         
                           passwd="password",           
                           db="events")
```

I couldent connect to my online database.

Usually I access manually to this database with *phpmyadmin* and the adress is something like **212.227.000.000/phpmyadmin**

So I tried something like

```
onlinedb = MySQLdb.connect( host="212.227.000.000" ...
```

or

```
onlinedb = MySQLdb.connect( host="212.227.000.000/phpmyadmin" ...
```

But I get an error such as:

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '212.227.000.000' (10061)")
```

Comment: just because phpmyadmin is on that IP doesn't mean mysql is. is mysql configured for TCP connections? Is that really the IP that mysql is running on?

Comment: And `php` here is for what?

Comment: And even if it was, you don't want to connect to phpMyAdmin anyway; you want to connect to the database itself; so why would you put phpmyadmin in the host string?

Comment: with the website I connect with php that way : $db = new database('root', 'password', 'databasename');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `212.227.000.000/phpmyadmin` is the URL of PHPMyAdmin (the thing you open in the browser). If so, the database may not be hosted on the machine with IP 212.227.000.000. You should check how PHPMyAdmin connects to the database. If PHPMyAdmin connects to 127.0.0.1, that probably means the database doesn't listen on the external IP address, and can't be reached over the network.

If you have ssh access to 212.227.000.000 you can check that with the `netstat` command:

```
$ netstat -pant | grep LISTEN | grep 3306
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:3306        0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      -
```

The 0.0.0.0 above indicates that MySQL is listening on all IPs, and barring any firewalls, you should be able to connect to the database.

Otherwise, if it says `127.0.0.1:3306`, the database can only be accessed from the machine itself and not over the network. In that case you can use an SSH tunnel.

Comment: thx for help. Yes it says 127.0.0.1:3306. So I should use an ssh tunnel with python? Sorry my knowledge is limited!

Comment: If the connection to the database needs to be stable over a longer period of time, I don't recommend an ssh tunnel. If you have control over the machine on which the database runs, you can change the MySQL configuration so it listens on the external IP, but that could be unsafe unless you use SSL connections (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html). Then again, I'm not sure Python supports secure connections.

You can look into an stunnel (https://www.stunnel.org) from the local machine to the remote machine, which will act similar to an SSH tunnel, but stable